# service worker generated by workbox-build comes error require is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, service-worker, workbox

I'm using workbox-build to generate `sw.js` for my web application, here is the build script named `build-sw.js`:

```js
const { injectManifest } = require('workbox-build');

// These are some common options, and not all are required.
// Consult the docs for more info.
injectManifest({
  dontCacheBustURLsMatching: /...../,
  globDirectory: './dist',
  globPatterns: [
    '**/*.js',
    '**/*.css',
    '**/*.svg'
  ],
  swDest: './dist/sw.js',
  swSrc: './sw-inject-source.js',
}).then(({count, size, warnings}) => {
  if (warnings.length > 0) {
    console.warn(
      'Warnings encountered while injecting the manifest:',
      warnings.join('\n')
    );
  }

  console.log(`Injected a manifest which will precache ${count} files, totaling ${size} bytes.`);
});
```

and here is the source code to generate `sw.js` named `sw-inject-source.js`:

```js
const { precacheAndRoute } = require('workbox-precaching/precacheAndRoute');
const { registerRoute } = require('workbox-routing');
const { StaleWhileRevalidate } = require('workbox-strategies');


precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

registerRoute(
    new RegExp('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random'),
    new StaleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: 'apiCache',
    })
);
```

But after I deploy the `sw.js` online, the `sw.js` comes the error:

```js
require is not defined.
```

It seems like that the module import code in `sw-inject-source.js` causes this error, I have no idea to fix this, could you please give some advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but as I came across the same problem and I think I have spotted the right track, I figured I'd write it here so that others can benefit.

Key aspect: `require` belongs to the Node.js (server-side) Javascript, but you are trying to build a JS file that will need to run in a web browser(!). That's the source of all misunderstanding.

This video that explains how they do it at Google will put you on the right track of the extra steps/tools that are needed.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOq92prx00w&t=419s&ab_channel=GoogleChromeDevelopers

Now this Jeff guy is compiling TypeScript, but there are other tools that can bring you from Node's JavaScript to browsers' JavaScript.

One thing is for sure: this worker thing is super convoluted. Information is scattered all over the place, old info is getting in the way, and there's a ton of info to absorb before one starts making sense of it all.

As far as I am concerned, I gave up trying to "convert" and I fell back  to the solution that imports workbox from the CDN as a script:

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.4.1/workbox-sw.js'
);

const {precacheAndRoute} = workbox.precaching
const {registerRoute} = workbox.routing
const {CacheFirst} = workbox.strategies
const {CacheableResponse} = workbox.cacheableResponse

// This will be replaced by the list of files to precache by
// the `workbox injectManifest` build step.
const manifest = self.__WB_MANIFEST;
precacheAndRoute(manifest);
```